# How can i create categories for specific users based on categories they posted in

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I dont know if i asked that question correctly but this is the general idea of what i want to do. I am creating a multi vendor store where user can post in any category they want. From their profile i created a "my store" that aggregates all they posted products into a store they can share the link using the code below

```
 $this['allproducts'] = Advert::
                    with('allimage')
                  ->where('user_id', $slug)
                  ->orderby('created_at','desc')
                  ->get();
```

Now i want a create a category list in the user's store that is made up of categories that have posted in to make it easy for buyers to navigate their products. I have tried something like

```
$this['items'] = Cat::
              whereHas('adverts')
             ->where('user_id', $slug)
             ->pluck('cat_title');
```

This throws up an error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'corymillz_adverts_cat.buy_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `cat_title`, `id` from `corymillz_adverts_cat` where exists (select * from `corymillz_adverts_` where `corymillz_adverts_cat`.`buy_id` = `corymillz_adverts_`.`cat_id`) and `user_id` = 133 order by `nest_left` asc)

and

```
$this['items'] = Cat::
              having('adverts')
             ->where('user_id', $slug)
             ->pluck('cat_title');
```

With this nothing happens

Advert and Cats has the following relationship

Advert Model

```
public $belongsTo = [
        'cats' => [

        'Corymillz\Adverts\Models\Cat',
        'table' => 'corymillz_adverts_adverts_cat',
        'order' => 'cat_title',
```

Cats Model

```
    public $hasMany = [
    'adverts' => [

        'Corymillz\Adverts\Models\Advert',
        'table' => 'corymillz_adverts_adverts_cat',
        'order' => 'title',


        ]
    ];
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "none has worked"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: This isn't normal Laravel is it?

Comment: No. Its octobercms built on laravel but almost everything works hand in hand

Comment: In your `Cat` model, we have to look at your `hasMany` relationship. So for what I can see in it, you have overridden the `table` to be your `cat` table, shouldn't this be your `adverts` table?

Comment: @OliverNybroe thats pivot table

Comment: @OsujiKingsley shouldn't it then be a `belongsToMany` relationship?